# Unstable work of splice in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I try to delete element from array of objects:

```
ng-click="deleteSpecialization(item)"
```

Where `item` is item from `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="item in data"
```

My function:

```
$scope.deleteSpecialization = function (item) {
   var index = $scope.data.indexOf(item);
   if (index != -1) {
      $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
   }    
}
```

This code removes some items in template HTML after second click. I do one `ng-click`but template changes incorrect.

Format:

```
[{"name":"A","checked":false,"id":"6"},{"name":"B","checked":false,"id":"8"},{"name":"C","checked":false,"id":"10"},{"name":"D","checked":false,"id":"12"},
```

Comment: can you create a sample http://plnkr.co/edit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working demo of splice functionality, although you write the absolutely fine for splice.

https://codepen.io/kashifmustafa/pen/VvjqwE

```
$scope.deleteSpecialization = function (item) {
   var index = $scope.data.indexOf(item);
   if (index != -1) {
      $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/qjcqwhsw/2/

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(item){
    var index = $scope.data.indexOf(item);    
    $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
};
```

hope this may help you

Comment: Does not work, when I delete one row Angular JS removes some rows in template HTML